# if statement in HTML with Python

Tags: python, html

I have to use an 'or' in Python and HTML.

```
 <div>
     {% if imp[3][0] == 'abc' || imp[3][0] == 'def' %}
         <p>yes</p>
     {% endif %}
 </div>
```

I get an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '|'
```

However, && for and works.
Any way?

Comment: what about using or instead of || ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using the keyword `or` not the Boolean operator `||`

```
<div>
     {% if imp[3][0] == 'abc' or imp[3][0] == 'def' %}
         <p>yes</p>
     {% endif %}
</div>
```

Of course using `in` would be better here:

```
<div>
     {% if imp[3][0] in ('abc', 'def') %}
         <p>yes</p>
     {% endif %}
</div>
```